# XML Returning Function - Failing To Return Based on IF

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a function that returns XML based on a transaction type, the XML has to be formatted differently for each transaction type.

I pass the name of the transaction to the function i.e.

```
svf_ReturnXML('My Transaction')
```

Now I have multiple transactions types so instead of doing a case when to change the parameters I send to the function I instead wrote the function similar to below:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[spf_ReturnXML]
(
    @RecordNo VARCHAR(10),
    @Branch VARCHAR(2),
    @PolicyRef VARCHAR(10),
    @Transaction VARCHAR(30),
    @PolicyNumber VARCHAR(18),
    @InceptionDate DATE,
    @RenewalDate DATE,
    @EffectiveDate DATE ,
    @PremXIPT DECIMAL(38, 2),
    @PremIPT DECIMAL(38, 2),
    @FeeXIPT DECIMAL(38, 2),
    @FeeIPT DECIMAL(38, 2)

)
RETURNS XML
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ret XML;

     /* This is where we return the XML for the query */


    IF (@Transaction = 'Endorsement')
        BEGIN
           SELECT @ret
            =

            (
                SELECT @RecordNo AS "PolicyRecordNumber",
                       @PolicyNumber AS "PCAdjustment/PolicyNumber",
                       --@InceptionDate AS "PCAdjustment/StartDate",
                       --@RenewalDate AS "PCAdjustment/ExpiryDate",
                       @EffectiveDate AS "PCAdjustment/EffectiveDate" ,
                       @PremXIPT AS "PCAdjustment/Premium/NetAmount",
                       @PremIPT AS "PCAdjustment/Premium/Ipt",
                       @FeeXIPT AS "PCAdjustment/Fee/NetAmount",
                       @FeeIPT AS "PCAdjustment/Fee/Ipt",
                       [dbo].[GetTitle](pc.[Name]) AS "PCAdjustment/Policyholder/PolicyholderType/PrivateIndividual/Name/Title",
                       pc.[Forenames] AS "PCAdjustment/Policyholder/PolicyholderType/PrivateIndividual/Name/FirstNames",
                       [dbo].[SVF_GetSurname](pc.[Name], pc.[Forenames]) AS "PCAdjustment/Policyholder/PolicyholderType/PrivateIndividual/Name/LastName",
                       pc.Birthdate AS "PCAdjustment/Policyholder/PolicyholderType/PrivateIndividual/DateOfBirth",
                       CASE
                           WHEN [Mar] IN ( 'Single', 'Married', 'Divorced', 'Separated', 'Widowed' ) THEN
                               [Mar]
                           ELSE
                               'Unknown'
                       END AS "PCAdjustment/Policyholder/PolicyholderType/PrivateIndividual/MaritalStatus",
                       c.[Sex] AS "PCAdjustment/Policyholder/PolicyholderType/PrivateIndividual/Sex",
                       c.[Name] AS "PCAdjustment/Policyholder/Contact",
                       [Addr1] AS "PCAdjustment/Policyholder/Address/Address1",
                       [Addr2] AS "PCAdjustment/Policyholder/Address/Address2",
                       [Addr3] AS "PCAdjustment/Policyholder/Address/Address3",
                       [Addr4] AS "PCAdjustment/Policyholder/Address/Address4",
                       [Pcode] AS "PCAdjustment/Policyholder/Address/Postcode",
                       ISNULL(dbo.Clean_Number([Tel]), dbo.Clean_Number([Tel2])) AS "PCAdjustment/Policyholder/Phone",
                       [Email] AS "PCAdjustment/Policyholder/Email",
                       CASE
                           WHEN cf.[Cover] = 'TP Only' THEN
                               'ThirdParty'
                           WHEN cf.Cover = 'TPFT' THEN
                               'ThirdPartyFireAndTheft'
                           WHEN cf.Cover = 'TP & T' THEN
                               'ThirdParty'
                           ELSE
                               cf.Cover
                       END AS "PCAdjustment/Cover/CoverType",
                       twxs.Excess_amt AS "PCAdjustment/Cover/PolicyExcess",
                       pc.[Own_ncb] AS "PCAdjustment/Cover/NoClaimsBonusYears",
                       pc.[Company_ncb] AS "PCAdjustment/Cover/NCBOtherVehicle",
            (
                SELECT *
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT 'PC32' 'TypeID',
                           'Overall' 'Applying',
                           0 'Amount'
                    UNION
                    SELECT CASE
                               WHEN cf.Protected_bonus = 'Yes' THEN
                                   'PC16'
                           END 'TypeID',
                           CASE
                               WHEN cf.Protected_bonus = 'Yes' THEN
                                   'Overall'
                           END 'Overall',
                           CASE
                               WHEN cf.Protected_bonus = 'Yes' THEN
                                   0
                           END 'Amount'
                    FROM
                    (
                        SELECT *
                        FROM First_ICP.dbo.ic_BD_CF cf
                        WHERE cf.B@ = @Branch
                              AND cf.PolRef@ = @PolicyRef
                    ) cf
                    WHERE CASE
                              WHEN cf.Protected_bonus = 'Yes' THEN
                                  'PC16'
                          END IS NOT NULL
                ) AS Tbl
                FOR XML PATH('Endorsement'), TYPE
            )          AS "PCAdjustment/Cover/Endorsements",
                       CASE
                           WHEN cf.Class_of_use = 'S D & P' THEN
                               'SocialDomesticAndPleasure'
                           WHEN cf.Class_of_use = 'Class 1' THEN
                               'Class1'
                           WHEN cf.Class_of_use = 'Class 2' THEN
                               'Class2'
                           WHEN cf.Class_of_use = 'Class 3' THEN
                               'Class3'
                       END AS "PCAdjustment/Cover/Use",
            (
                SELECT Drivers.RelationshipToPH 'RelationshipToPolicyholder',
            (
                SELECT dri2.Drivertitle 'Title',
                       dri2.FirstName 'FirstNames',
                       dri2.Surname 'LastName'
                FROM dbo.tvf_Tradewise_RetrieveDriverDetails(@Branch, @PolicyRef) dri2
                WHERE Drivers.B@ = dri2.B@
                      AND Drivers.PolRef@ = dri2.PolRef@
                      AND Drivers.Driver = dri2.Driver
                FOR XML PATH('Name'), TYPE
            )   ,
                       Drivers.DOB 'DateOfBirth',
                       Drivers.Licence 'LicenceType',
                       Drivers.LicenceHeld 'PeriodLicenceHeld',
            (
                SELECT c.Addr1 'Address1',
                       c.Addr2 'Address2',
                       c.Addr3 'Address3',
                       c.Addr4 'Address4',
                       c.Pcode 'Postcode'
                WHERE c.B@ = @Branch
                      AND c.Ref@ = SUBSTRING(@PolicyRef, 1, 6)
                FOR XML PATH('HomeAddress'), TYPE
            )   ,
                       Drivers.PeriodResident 'PeriodResident',
                       Drivers.VehFreq 'VehicleUseFrequency',
                       Drivers.OtherVehs 'HasUseOfOtherVehicle',
                       ISNULL(Drivers.Occupation, [Drivers].[2ndOccupation]) 'MainOccupation',
                       Drivers.[2ndOccupation] 'SecondaryOccupation',
                       Drivers.RefIns 'MotorInsuranceRefusalDetails',
                       Drivers.Accconv 'HasCriminalConvictions',
            (
                SELECT 'false' 'Removed',
                       TWClaimType 'ClaimType',
                       IncidentDate,
                       Amount
                FROM dbo.tvf_Tradewise_RetrieveDriverClaims(@Branch, @PolicyRef) tvfc
                WHERE Drivers.B@ = tvfc.Branch
                      AND Drivers.PolRef@ = tvfc.PolicyRef
                      AND Drivers.Driver = tvfc.Driver
                FOR XML PATH('DriverClaim'), TYPE
            )          AS "Claims",
            (
                SELECT 'false' 'Removed',
                       tvfcon.ConvCode 'ConvictionCode',
                       tvfcon.ConvDate 'ConvictionDate',
                       tvfcon.Amount 'Fine'
                FROM dbo.tvf_Tradewise_RetrieveDriverConvictions(@Branch, @PolicyRef) tvfcon
                WHERE Drivers.B@ = tvfcon.Branch
                      AND Drivers.PolRef@ = tvfcon.PolicyRef
                      AND Drivers.Driver = tvfcon.Driver
                FOR XML PATH('DriverConviction'), TYPE
            )          AS "Convictions",
            (
                SELECT 'false' 'Removed',
                       tvfm.Description,
                       DATEDIFF(YEAR, CONVERT(DATE, Drivers.DOB, 103), ISNULL(tvfm.[Diab Date Since], GETDATE())) 'AgeDiagnosed',
                       tvfm.Medication,
                       tvfm.[DVLA Notified] 'DvlaNotified',
                       tvfm.CondNote 'ConditionDeteriorating',
                       tvfm.LicRest 'LicenceRestricted'
                FROM dbo.tvf_Tradewise_RetrieveDriverMedical(@Branch, @PolicyRef) tvfm
                WHERE Drivers.B@ = tvfm.B@
                      AND Drivers.PolRef@ = tvfm.PolRef@
                      AND Drivers.Driver = tvfm.Driver
                FOR XML PATH('DriverMedicalCondition'), TYPE
            )          AS "MedicalConditions"
                FROM dbo.tvf_Tradewise_RetrieveDriverDetails(@Branch, @PolicyRef) Drivers
                WHERE Drivers.B@ = @Branch
                      AND Drivers.PolRef@ = @PolicyRef
                FOR XML PATH('Driver'), TYPE
            )          AS "PCAdjustment/Drivers",
                       cf.Make AS "PCAdjustment/Vehicles/Vehicle/Make",
                       cf.Model AS "PCAdjustment/Vehicles/Vehicle/Model",
                       cf.Reg AS "PCAdjustment/Vehicles/Vehicle/RegistrationNumber",
                       CASE
                           WHEN [Body] = 'Cabriolet' THEN
                               'Convertible'
                           WHEN cf.Body = 'Coupe'
                                OR cf.Body = 'M''aravan'
                                OR cf.Body = 'Pickup' THEN
                               'Other'
                           WHEN cf.Body = 'Estate'
                                OR cf.Body = 'Hatchback'
                                OR cf.Body = 'Saloon'
                                OR cf.Body = 'Van' THEN
                               cf.Body
                           ELSE
                               'Unknown'
                       END AS "PCAdjustment/Vehicles/Vehicle/BodyType",
                       CASE
                           WHEN [Parking] = '*Sec.PublicCPark'
                                OR cf.Parking = 'Car Park' THEN
                               'CarPark'
                           WHEN cf.Parking = '*Unlocked Garage' THEN
                               'UnlockedBuilding'
                           WHEN cf.Parking = 'Carport'
                                OR cf.Parking = 'Locked Building'
                                OR cf.Parking = 'Locked Compound'
                                OR cf.Parking = 'Private Property'
                                OR cf.Parking = 'Public Road'
                                OR cf.Parking = 'UnlockedBuilding'
                                OR cf.Parking = 'UnlockedCompound' THEN
                               REPLACE(cf.[Parking], ' ', '')
                           WHEN cf.Parking = 'Garaged' THEN
                               'Garage'
                           WHEN cf.Parking = 'Kept on 3rdParty' THEN
                               'ThirdPartyPremises'
                           WHEN cf.Parking = 'Parked on Drive' THEN
                               'Drive'
                       END AS "PCAdjustment/Vehicles/Vehicle/LocationWhenNotInUse",
            (
                SELECT SUM(Mileage)
                FROM dbo.tvf_Tradewise_RetrieveDriverDetails(@Branch, @PolicyRef)
                GROUP BY B@,
                         PolRef@
            )          AS "PCAdjustment/Vehicles/Vehicle/AnnualMileage",
                       YEAR([Date_made]) AS "PCAdjustment/Vehicles/Vehicle/YearOfManufacture",
                       cf.Engine_size AS "PCAdjustment/Vehicles/Vehicle/EngineSizeCc",
                       cf.Purchasedate AS "PCAdjustment/Vehicles/Vehicle/PurchaseDate",
                       cf.Value AS "PCAdjustment/Vehicles/Vehicle/PurchasePrice",
                       NULL AS "PCAdjustment/Vehicles/Vehicle/EstimatedValue",
                       cf.Seats AS "PCAdjustment/Vehicles/Vehicle/NumberOfSeats",
                       CASE
                           WHEN [Lhd] = 'No' THEN
                               'true'
                           ELSE
                               'false'
                       END AS "PCAdjustment/Vehicles/Vehicle/RightHandDrive",
                       cf.Fuel AS "PCAdjustment/Vehicles/Vehicle/FuelType"
                FROM First_ICP.dbo.ic_brpolicy p
                    INNER JOIN [First_ICP].[dbo].[ic_BD_CF] AS cf
                        ON p.B@ = cf.[B@]
                           AND p.PolRef@ = cf.[PolRef@]
                    INNER JOIN [First_ICP].[dbo].[ic_yyclient] AS c
                        ON cf.[B@] = c.[B@]
                           AND cf.[Ref@] = c.[Ref@]
                    INNER JOIN [First_ICP].[dbo].[ic_BD_PC] AS pc
                        ON cf.[B@] = pc.[B@]
                           AND cf.[PolRef@] = pc.[PolRef@]
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [First_ICP].dbo.ic_BD_TWXS twxs
                        ON twxs.B@ = p.B@
                           AND twxs.PolRef@ = p.PolRef@
                    INNER JOIN dbo.tvf_Tradewise_RetrieveDriverDetails(@Branch, @PolicyRef) tvfDrivers
                        ON tvfDrivers.B@ = p.B@
                           AND tvfDrivers.PolRef@ = p.PolRef@
                           AND tvfDrivers.Driver = 0
                WHERE p.B@ = @Branch
                      AND p.PolRef@ = @PolicyRef
                FOR XML PATH('Policy'), TYPE
            ) 

    IF (@Transaction = 'New Business')
    BEGIN;
    SELECT @ret
            =
        (
            SELECT @RecordNo AS "PolicyRecordNumber",
                   @PolicyNumber AS "PCNewBusiness/PolicyNumber",
                   @InceptionDate AS "PCNewBusiness/StartDate",
                   @RenewalDate AS "PCNewBusiness/ExpiryDate",
                   @PremXIPT AS "PCNewBusiness/Premium/NetAmount",
                   @PremIPT AS "PCNewBusiness/Premium/Ipt",
                   @FeeXIPT AS "PCNewBusiness/Fee/NetAmount",
                   @FeeIPT AS "PCNewBusiness/Fee/Ipt",
                   [dbo].[GetTitle](pc.[Name]) AS "PCNewBusiness/Policyholder/PolicyholderType/PrivateIndividual/Name/Title",
                   pc.[Forenames] AS "PCNewBusiness/Policyholder/PolicyholderType/PrivateIndividual/Name/FirstNames",
                   [dbo].[SVF_GetSurname](pc.[Name], pc.[Forenames]) AS "PCNewBusiness/Policyholder/PolicyholderType/PrivateIndividual/Name/LastName",
                   pc.Birthdate AS "PCNewBusiness/Policyholder/PolicyholderType/PrivateIndividual/DateOfBirth",
                   CASE
                       WHEN [Mar] IN ( 'Single', 'Married', 'Divorced', 'Separated', 'Widowed' ) THEN
                           [Mar]
                       ELSE
                           'Unknown'
                   END AS "PCNewBusiness/Policyholder/PolicyholderType/PrivateIndividual/MaritalStatus",
                   c.[Sex] AS "PCNewBusiness/Policyholder/PolicyholderType/PrivateIndividual/Sex",
                   c.[Name] AS "PCNewBusiness/Policyholder/Contact",
                   [Addr1] AS "PCNewBusiness/Policyholder/Address/Address1",
                   [Addr2] AS "PCNewBusiness/Policyholder/Address/Address2",
                   [Addr3] AS "PCNewBusiness/Policyholder/Address/Address3",
                   [Addr4] AS "PCNewBusiness/Policyholder/Address/Address4",
                   [Pcode] AS "PCNewBusiness/Policyholder/Address/Postcode",
                   ISNULL(dbo.Clean_Number([Tel]), dbo.Clean_Number([Tel2])) AS "PCNewBusiness/Policyholder/Phone",
                   [Email] AS "PCNewBusiness/Policyholder/Email",
                   CASE
                       WHEN cf.[Cover] = 'TP Only' THEN
                           'ThirdParty'
                       WHEN cf.Cover = 'TPFT' THEN
                           'ThirdPartyFireAndTheft'
                       WHEN cf.Cover = 'TP & T' THEN
                           'ThirdParty'
                       ELSE
                           cf.Cover
                   END AS "PCNewBusiness/Cover/CoverType",
                   twxs.Excess_amt AS "PCNewBusiness/Cover/PolicyExcess",
                   pc.[Own_ncb] AS "PCNewBusiness/Cover/NoClaimsBonusYears",
                   pc.[Company_ncb] AS "PCNewBusiness/Cover/NCBOtherVehicle",
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM
            (
                SELECT 'PC32' 'TypeID',
                       'Overall' 'Applying',
                       0 'Amount'
                UNION
                SELECT CASE
                           WHEN cf.Protected_bonus = 'Yes' THEN
                               'PC16'
                       END 'TypeID',
                       CASE
                           WHEN cf.Protected_bonus = 'Yes' THEN
                               'Overall'
                       END 'Overall',
                       CASE
                           WHEN cf.Protected_bonus = 'Yes' THEN
                               0
                       END 'Amount'
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT *
                    FROM First_ICP.dbo.ic_BD_CF cf
                    WHERE cf.B@ = @Branch
                          AND cf.PolRef@ = @PolicyRef
                ) cf
                WHERE CASE
                          WHEN cf.Protected_bonus = 'Yes' THEN
                              'PC16'
                      END IS NOT NULL
            ) AS Tbl
            FOR XML PATH('Endorsement'), TYPE
        )          AS "PCNewBusiness/Cover/Endorsements",
                   CASE
                       WHEN cf.Class_of_use = 'S D & P' THEN
                           'SocialDomesticAndPleasure'
                       WHEN cf.Class_of_use = 'Class 1' THEN
                           'Class1'
                       WHEN cf.Class_of_use = 'Class 2' THEN
                           'Class2'
                       WHEN cf.Class_of_use = 'Class 3' THEN
                           'Class3'
                   END AS "PCNewBusiness/Cover/Use",
        (
            SELECT Drivers.RelationshipToPH 'RelationshipToPolicyholder',
        (
            SELECT dri2.Drivertitle 'Title',
                   dri2.FirstName 'FirstNames',
                   dri2.Surname 'LastName'
            FROM dbo.tvf_Tradewise_RetrieveDriverDetails(@Branch, @PolicyRef) dri2
            WHERE Drivers.B@ = dri2.B@
                  AND Drivers.PolRef@ = dri2.PolRef@
                  AND Drivers.Driver = dri2.Driver
            FOR XML PATH('Name'), TYPE
        )   ,
                   Drivers.DOB 'DateOfBirth',
                   Drivers.Licence 'LicenceType',
                   Drivers.LicenceHeld 'PeriodLicenceHeld',
        (
            SELECT c.Addr1 'Address1',
                   c.Addr2 'Address2',
                   c.Addr3 'Address3',
                   c.Addr4 'Address4',
                   c.Pcode 'Postcode'
            WHERE c.B@ = @Branch
                  AND c.Ref@ = SUBSTRING(@PolicyRef, 1, 6)
            FOR XML PATH('HomeAddress'), TYPE
        )   ,
                   Drivers.PeriodResident 'PeriodResident',
                   Drivers.VehFreq 'VehicleUseFrequency',
                   Drivers.OtherVehs 'HasUseOfOtherVehicle',
                   ISNULL(Drivers.Occupation, [Drivers].[2ndOccupation]) 'MainOccupation',
                   Drivers.[2ndOccupation] 'SecondaryOccupation',
                   Drivers.RefIns 'MotorInsuranceRefusalDetails',
                   Drivers.Accconv 'HasCriminalConvictions',
        (
            SELECT 'false' 'Removed',
                   TWClaimType 'ClaimType',
                   IncidentDate,
                   Amount
            FROM dbo.tvf_Tradewise_RetrieveDriverClaims(@Branch, @PolicyRef) tvfc
            WHERE Drivers.B@ = tvfc.Branch
                  AND Drivers.PolRef@ = tvfc.PolicyRef
                  AND Drivers.Driver = tvfc.Driver
            FOR XML PATH('DriverClaim'), TYPE
        )          AS "Claims",
        (
            SELECT 'false' 'Removed',
                   tvfcon.ConvCode 'ConvictionCode',
                   tvfcon.ConvDate 'ConvictionDate',
                   tvfcon.Amount 'Fine'
            FROM dbo.tvf_Tradewise_RetrieveDriverConvictions(@Branch, @PolicyRef) tvfcon
            WHERE Drivers.B@ = tvfcon.Branch
                  AND Drivers.PolRef@ = tvfcon.PolicyRef
                  AND Drivers.Driver = tvfcon.Driver
            FOR XML PATH('DriverConviction'), TYPE
        )          AS "Convictions",
        (
            SELECT 'false' 'Removed',
                   tvfm.Description,
                   DATEDIFF(YEAR, CONVERT(DATE, Drivers.DOB, 103), ISNULL(tvfm.[Diab Date Since], GETDATE())) 'AgeDiagnosed',
                   tvfm.Medication,
                   tvfm.[DVLA Notified] 'DvlaNotified',
                   tvfm.CondNote 'ConditionDeteriorating',
                   tvfm.LicRest 'LicenceRestricted'
            FROM dbo.tvf_Tradewise_RetrieveDriverMedical(@Branch, @PolicyRef) tvfm
            WHERE Drivers.B@ = tvfm.B@
                  AND Drivers.PolRef@ = tvfm.PolRef@
                  AND Drivers.Driver = tvfm.Driver
            FOR XML PATH('DriverMedicalCondition'), TYPE
        )          AS "MedicalConditions"
            FROM dbo.tvf_Tradewise_RetrieveDriverDetails(@Branch, @PolicyRef) Drivers
            WHERE Drivers.B@ = @Branch
                  AND Drivers.PolRef@ = @PolicyRef
            FOR XML PATH('Driver'), TYPE
        )          AS "PCNewBusiness/Drivers",
                   cf.Make AS "PCNewBusiness/Vehicles/Vehicle/Make",
                   cf.Model AS "PCNewBusiness/Vehicles/Vehicle/Model",
                   cf.Reg AS "PCNewBusiness/Vehicles/Vehicle/RegistrationNumber",
                   CASE
                       WHEN [Body] = 'Cabriolet' THEN
                           'Convertible'
                       WHEN cf.Body = 'Coupe'
                            OR cf.Body = 'M''aravan'
                            OR cf.Body = 'Pickup' THEN
                           'Other'
                       WHEN cf.Body = 'Estate'
                            OR cf.Body = 'Hatchback'
                            OR cf.Body = 'Saloon'
                            OR cf.Body = 'Van' THEN
                           cf.Body
                       ELSE
                           'Unknown'
                   END AS "PCNewBusiness/Vehicles/Vehicle/BodyType",
                   CASE
                       WHEN [Parking] = '*Sec.PublicCPark'
                            OR cf.Parking = 'Car Park' THEN
                           'CarPark'
                       WHEN cf.Parking = '*Unlocked Garage' THEN
                           'UnlockedBuilding'
                       WHEN cf.Parking = 'Carport'
                            OR cf.Parking = 'Locked Building'
                            OR cf.Parking = 'Locked Compound'
                            OR cf.Parking = 'Private Property'
                            OR cf.Parking = 'Public Road'
                            OR cf.Parking = 'UnlockedBuilding'
                            OR cf.Parking = 'UnlockedCompound' THEN
                           REPLACE(cf.[Parking], ' ', '')
                       WHEN cf.Parking = 'Garaged' THEN
                           'Garage'
                       WHEN cf.Parking = 'Kept on 3rdParty' THEN
                           'ThirdPartyPremises'
                       WHEN cf.Parking = 'Parked on Drive' THEN
                           'Drive'
                   END AS "PCNewBusiness/Vehicles/Vehicle/LocationWhenNotInUse",
        (
            SELECT SUM(Mileage)
            FROM dbo.tvf_Tradewise_RetrieveDriverDetails(@Branch, @PolicyRef)
            GROUP BY B@,
                     PolRef@
        )          AS "PCNewBusiness/Vehicles/Vehicle/AnnualMileage",
                   YEAR([Date_made]) AS "PCNewBusiness/Vehicles/Vehicle/YearOfManufacture",
                   cf.Engine_size AS "PCNewBusiness/Vehicles/Vehicle/EngineSizeCc",
                   cf.Purchasedate AS "PCNewBusiness/Vehicles/Vehicle/PurchaseDate",
                   cf.Value AS "PCNewBusiness/Vehicles/Vehicle/PurchasePrice",
                   NULL AS "PCNewBusiness/Vehicles/Vehicle/EstimatedValue",
                   cf.Seats AS "PCNewBusiness/Vehicles/Vehicle/NumberOfSeats",
                   CASE
                       WHEN [Lhd] = 'No' THEN
                           'true'
                       ELSE
                           'false'
                   END AS "PCNewBusiness/Vehicles/Vehicle/RightHandDrive",
                   cf.Fuel AS "PCNewBusiness/Vehicles/Vehicle/FuelType"
            FROM First_ICP.dbo.ic_brpolicy p
                INNER JOIN [First_ICP].[dbo].[ic_BD_CF] AS cf
                    ON p.B@ = cf.[B@]
                       AND p.PolRef@ = cf.[PolRef@]
                INNER JOIN [First_ICP].[dbo].[ic_yyclient] AS c
                    ON cf.[B@] = c.[B@]
                       AND cf.[Ref@] = c.[Ref@]
                INNER JOIN [First_ICP].[dbo].[ic_BD_PC] AS pc
                    ON cf.[B@] = pc.[B@]
                       AND cf.[PolRef@] = pc.[PolRef@]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [First_ICP].dbo.ic_BD_TWXS twxs
                    ON twxs.B@ = p.B@
                       AND twxs.PolRef@ = p.PolRef@
                INNER JOIN dbo.tvf_Tradewise_RetrieveDriverDetails(@Branch, @PolicyRef) tvfDrivers
                    ON tvfDrivers.B@ = p.B@
                       AND tvfDrivers.PolRef@ = p.PolRef@
                       AND tvfDrivers.Driver = 0
            WHERE p.B@ = @Branch
                  AND p.PolRef@ = @PolicyRef
            FOR XML PATH('Policy'), TYPE
        )

        IF (@Transaction = 'Renewal')
        BEGIN
            SELECT @ret
                =
            (
                SELECT @RecordNo AS "PolicyRecordNumber",
                       @PolicyNumber AS "PCRenewal/PolicyNumber",
                       --@InceptionDate AS "PCRenewal/StartDate",
                       @RenewalDate AS "PCRenewal/ExpiryDate",
                       @PremXIPT AS "PCRenewal/Premium/NetAmount",
                       @PremIPT AS "PCRenewal/Premium/Ipt",
                       @FeeXIPT AS "PCRenewal/Fee/NetAmount",
                       @FeeIPT AS "PCRenewal/Fee/Ipt",
                       [dbo].[GetTitle](pc.[Name]) AS "PCRenewal/Policyholder/PolicyholderType/PrivateIndividual/Name/Title",
                       pc.[Forenames] AS "PCRenewal/Policyholder/PolicyholderType/PrivateIndividual/Name/FirstNames",
                       [dbo].[SVF_GetSurname](pc.[Name], pc.[Forenames]) AS "PCRenewal/Policyholder/PolicyholderType/PrivateIndividual/Name/LastName",
                       pc.Birthdate AS "PCRenewal/Policyholder/PolicyholderType/PrivateIndividual/DateOfBirth",
                       CASE
                           WHEN [Mar] IN ( 'Single', 'Married', 'Divorced', 'Separated', 'Widowed' ) THEN
                               [Mar]
                           ELSE
                               'Unknown'
                       END AS "PCRenewal/Policyholder/PolicyholderType/PrivateIndividual/MaritalStatus",
                       c.[Sex] AS "PCRenewal/Policyholder/PolicyholderType/PrivateIndividual/Sex",
                       c.[Name] AS "PCRenewal/Policyholder/Contact",
                       [Addr1] AS "PCRenewal/Policyholder/Address/Address1",
                       [Addr2] AS "PCRenewal/Policyholder/Address/Address2",
                       [Addr3] AS "PCRenewal/Policyholder/Address/Address3",
                       [Addr4] AS "PCRenewal/Policyholder/Address/Address4",
                       [Pcode] AS "PCRenewal/Policyholder/Address/Postcode",
                       ISNULL(dbo.Clean_Number([Tel]), dbo.Clean_Number([Tel2])) AS "PCRenewal/Policyholder/Phone",
                       [Email] AS "PCRenewal/Policyholder/Email",
                       CASE
                           WHEN cf.[Cover] = 'TP Only' THEN
                               'ThirdParty'
                           WHEN cf.Cover = 'TPFT' THEN
                               'ThirdPartyFireAndTheft'
                           WHEN cf.Cover = 'TP & T' THEN
                               'ThirdParty'
                           ELSE
                               cf.Cover
                       END AS "PCRenewal/Cover/CoverType",
                       twxs.Excess_amt AS "PCRenewal/Cover/PolicyExcess",
                       pc.[Own_ncb] AS "PCRenewal/Cover/NoClaimsBonusYears",
                       pc.[Company_ncb] AS "PCRenewal/Cover/NCBOtherVehicle",
            (
                SELECT *
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT 'PC32' 'TypeID',
                           'Overall' 'Applying',
                           0 'Amount'
                    UNION
                    SELECT CASE
                               WHEN cf.Protected_bonus = 'Yes' THEN
                                   'PC16'
                           END 'TypeID',
                           CASE
                               WHEN cf.Protected_bonus = 'Yes' THEN
                                   'Overall'
                           END 'Overall',
                           CASE
                               WHEN cf.Protected_bonus = 'Yes' THEN
                                   0
                           END 'Amount'
                    FROM
                    (
                        SELECT *
                        FROM First_ICP.dbo.ic_BD_CF cf
                        WHERE cf.B@ = @Branch
                              AND cf.PolRef@ = @PolicyRef
                    ) cf
                    WHERE CASE
                              WHEN cf.Protected_bonus = 'Yes' THEN
                                  'PC16'
                          END IS NOT NULL
                ) AS Tbl
                FOR XML PATH('Endorsement'), TYPE
            )          AS "PCRenewal/Cover/Endorsements",
                       CASE
                           WHEN cf.Class_of_use = 'S D & P' THEN
                               'SocialDomesticAndPleasure'
                           WHEN cf.Class_of_use = 'Class 1' THEN
                               'Class1'
                           WHEN cf.Class_of_use = 'Class 2' THEN
                               'Class2'
                           WHEN cf.Class_of_use = 'Class 3' THEN
                               'Class3'
                       END AS "PCRenewal/Cover/Use",
            (
                SELECT Drivers.RelationshipToPH 'RelationshipToPolicyholder',
            (
                SELECT dri2.Drivertitle 'Title',
                       dri2.FirstName 'FirstNames',
                       dri2.Surname 'LastName'
                FROM dbo.tvf_Tradewise_RetrieveDriverDetails(@Branch, @PolicyRef) dri2
                WHERE Drivers.B@ = dri2.B@
                      AND Drivers.PolRef@ = dri2.PolRef@
                      AND Drivers.Driver = dri2.Driver
                FOR XML PATH('Name'), TYPE
            )   ,
                       Drivers.DOB 'DateOfBirth',
                       Drivers.Licence 'LicenceType',
                       Drivers.LicenceHeld 'PeriodLicenceHeld',
            (
                SELECT c.Addr1 'Address1',
                       c.Addr2 'Address2',
                       c.Addr3 'Address3',
                       c.Addr4 'Address4',
                       c.Pcode 'Postcode'
                WHERE c.B@ = @Branch
                      AND c.Ref@ = SUBSTRING(@PolicyRef, 1, 6)
                FOR XML PATH('HomeAddress'), TYPE
            )   ,
                       Drivers.PeriodResident 'PeriodResident',
                       Drivers.VehFreq 'VehicleUseFrequency',
                       Drivers.OtherVehs 'HasUseOfOtherVehicle',
                       ISNULL(Drivers.Occupation, [Drivers].[2ndOccupation]) 'MainOccupation',
                       Drivers.[2ndOccupation] 'SecondaryOccupation',
                       Drivers.RefIns 'MotorInsuranceRefusalDetails',
                       Drivers.Accconv 'HasCriminalConvictions',
            (
                SELECT 'false' 'Removed',
                       TWClaimType 'ClaimType',
                       IncidentDate,
                       Amount
                FROM dbo.tvf_Tradewise_RetrieveDriverClaims(@Branch, @PolicyRef) tvfc
                WHERE Drivers.B@ = tvfc.Branch
                      AND Drivers.PolRef@ = tvfc.PolicyRef
                      AND Drivers.Driver = tvfc.Driver
                FOR XML PATH('DriverClaim'), TYPE
            )          AS "Claims",
            (
                SELECT 'false' 'Removed',
                       tvfcon.ConvCode 'ConvictionCode',
                       tvfcon.ConvDate 'ConvictionDate',
                       tvfcon.Amount 'Fine'
                FROM dbo.tvf_Tradewise_RetrieveDriverConvictions(@Branch, @PolicyRef) tvfcon
                WHERE Drivers.B@ = tvfcon.Branch
                      AND Drivers.PolRef@ = tvfcon.PolicyRef
                      AND Drivers.Driver = tvfcon.Driver
                FOR XML PATH('DriverConviction'), TYPE
            )          AS "Convictions",
            (
                SELECT 'false' 'Removed',
                       tvfm.Description,
                       DATEDIFF(YEAR, CONVERT(DATE, Drivers.DOB, 103), ISNULL(tvfm.[Diab Date Since], GETDATE())) 'AgeDiagnosed',
                       tvfm.Medication,
                       tvfm.[DVLA Notified] 'DvlaNotified',
                       tvfm.CondNote 'ConditionDeteriorating',
                       tvfm.LicRest 'LicenceRestricted'
                FROM dbo.tvf_Tradewise_RetrieveDriverMedical(@Branch, @PolicyRef) tvfm
                WHERE Drivers.B@ = tvfm.B@
                      AND Drivers.PolRef@ = tvfm.PolRef@
                      AND Drivers.Driver = tvfm.Driver
                FOR XML PATH('DriverMedicalCondition'), TYPE
            )          AS "MedicalConditions"
                FROM dbo.tvf_Tradewise_RetrieveDriverDetails(@Branch, @PolicyRef) Drivers
                WHERE Drivers.B@ = @Branch
                      AND Drivers.PolRef@ = @PolicyRef
                FOR XML PATH('Driver'), TYPE
            )          AS "PCRenewal/Drivers",                        
                FROM First_ICP.dbo.ic_brpolicy p
                    INNER JOIN [First_ICP].[dbo].[ic_BD_CF] AS cf
                        ON p.B@ = cf.[B@]
                           AND p.PolRef@ = cf.[PolRef@]
                    INNER JOIN [First_ICP].[dbo].[ic_yyclient] AS c
                        ON cf.[B@] = c.[B@]
                           AND cf.[Ref@] = c.[Ref@]
                    INNER JOIN [First_ICP].[dbo].[ic_BD_PC] AS pc
                        ON cf.[B@] = pc.[B@]
                           AND cf.[PolRef@] = pc.[PolRef@]
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [First_ICP].dbo.ic_BD_TWXS twxs
                        ON twxs.B@ = p.B@
                           AND twxs.PolRef@ = p.PolRef@
                    INNER JOIN dbo.tvf_Tradewise_RetrieveDriverDetails(@Branch, @PolicyRef) tvfDrivers
                        ON tvfDrivers.B@ = p.B@
                           AND tvfDrivers.PolRef@ = p.PolRef@
                           AND tvfDrivers.Driver = 0
                WHERE p.B@ = @Branch
                      AND p.PolRef@ = @PolicyRef
                FOR XML PATH('Policy'), TYPE
            );
        END;


        END;
    END;
    RETURN @ret;
END;
```

However what is occuring is whichever transaction type i.e. in this case Endorsement is at the top, it only returns the XML for Endorsement Transactions it doesn't return them for any other rows.

If I put the 'New Business' IF statement above the 'Endorsement' it only returns for the New Business, essentially it looks like it is only qualifying the first IF.

I have this in a Stored Procedure that works perfectly fine but want to run this against a table of data a populate a column with the XML.

Thoughts/Advice?

Comment: You have slimmed this down so much it doesn't really work. The function in your code is a different name and is only passing a single value. The function you posted has several.

Comment: I will post the full thing then.

Comment: I would start by moving each branch to its own function. This is way too much code to try to maintain in a single block like this. But more importantly....how are you calling this?

Comment: Hi Sean, I have already put it each branch to its single function now, I was just trying to avoid doing so.

Comment: So what is your question? Performance will be very challenging if you keep multiple paths in here. https://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/09/15/multiple-execution-paths/